How to return ListBox selected option when I click Submit button?
I want ListBoxGetChoice() function to return ListBox1 selected option when I click Submit button...
ListBoxGetChoice() {
  MyGui := Gui('AlwaysOnTop')
  MyGui.AddText(, 'Select your category')
  ListBox1 := MyGui.AddListBox('r6', ['Option1', 'Option2', 'Option3'])
  MyBtn1 := MyGui.AddButton('Default w80', 'Submit')
  MyGui.Show('w400')
  return ListBox1.Text ; This doesn't work
}


I believe achieving the desired outcome in the manner you propose is not feasible. When using the return statement within the function responsible for creating the Graphical User Interface (GUI), the return will be executed immediately upon the function's completion rather than being triggered by an internal action.
Therefore, it is advisable to adopt a more modular and event-driven approach in your code structure. By separating responsibilities, the GUI creation function should focus solely on that task, while specific actions are handled in dedicated functions or sub-functions. This architectural design enhances code modularity and organization, facilitating maintenance and future expansion.
Hence, I suggest considering the implementation of additional functions to manage the desired internal actions or creating sub-functions within the GUI context, as appropriate for the specific case. This practice not only enhances code clarity and readability but also fosters a more robust and scalable code structure.
ListBoxGetChoiceEXAMPLE1()
ListBoxGetChoiceEXAMPLE2()

ListBoxGetChoiceEXAMPLE1() {
    Global listbox1 ;   Your gui is inside a function, so lets turn the listbox1 a global 
    MyGui := Gui('AlwaysOnTop')
    MyGui.AddText(, 'Select your category')
    listbox1 := MyGui.AddListBox('r6', ['Select Me Option1', 'Select Me Option2', 'Select Me Option3'])
    MyGui.AddButton('Default w80', 'Submit').OnEvent("Click", submit)   ;   call submit button function
    MyGui.Show('x0 y0 w400')
    
    submit(ctrl,info)   {
        
        msgbox  listbox1.Text
    }

}


;################

ListBoxGetChoiceEXAMPLE2() {
    MyGui := Gui('AlwaysOnTop')
    MyGui.AddText(, 'Select your category')
    MyGui.AddListBox('r6', ['Double Click Me Option1', 'Double Click Me Option2', 'Double Click Me Option3']).OnEvent("DoubleClick", listbox)   ; call on double click an item
    MyGui.Show('x500 y0 w400')

    listbox(ctrl,info)  {
    
        msgbox  ctrl.Text
    }
}

